# How to use ripgrep to replace all matches within all files?

Tags: ripgrep

I can use the following command to print all changed file and content in the stdout

```bash
rg --passthru -F "red" -r "green" -N
```

Output:

```bash
ip.txt
blue test1
green 2
hello blue world

ip2.txt
blue test1
green 2
hello blue world

ip3.txt
green test1
green 2
hello green world

ip4.txt
green test1
green 2
hello green world
```

how to write these files with changed content to the original file.

Answer (score 2):

You can't with ripgrep alone. ripgrep doesn't support it by design. It never writes to files. It only reads them.

Comment: do you know how to integrate with other tools to do this?

Comment: Try the FAQ: https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep/blob/master/FAQ.md#search-and-replace